# Are $n$-vector bundles an $(\infty,n)$-symmetric monoidal category with duals?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ag.algebraic-geometry

In Lurie's On the Classification of Topological Field Theories, one of the main characters are $(\infty,n)$-symmetric monoidal category with duals. A basic example of this should be $n$-vector spaces, and so it is natural to extend this intuition to $n$-modules on a commutative ring, which in nice cases should be the local picture of $n$-vector bundles on a topological space, and in the general situation of quasi-coherent sheaves of $n$-modules over a ringed space.

Is there any available treatment of this subject?

Thanks,

d.

Comment: I don't even know any references for $n$-vector spaces, $n$-modules, $n$-algebras, etc.

Comment: One of the possible meanings (maybe not the most standard) of "n-vector space" is complex of vector spaces that is concentrated in degrees {0,1,..,n-1}.

Comment: Toen and Vezzosi have some thoughts about $n=2$. Also, they give further references. arXiv:0804.1274, arXiv:0903.3292.